# Xamarin iOS ipa file size issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio, ipa

Project structure with PCL based approach:

Project X (solution)

- Core (Base project with autofac for Ioc based setup)
- Project (90% of code common for droid and ios)
- Project.Droid (Droid settings, renderers and graphics. )
- Project.iOS (iOS settings, renderers and graphics. )

I have gone through all possible options to reduce ipa file size. esp with linking.
I have used 'Link all' and stripping debug code, optimizing image etc.

Final ipa size is 77 MB.

Here are the details of file sizes after exploring package contents. I am using arch 7 and 64.

**Project.iOS is 42 MB**
This is bothering. Since I can see dll's and images separately along with this file. Not sure why its taking so much space. Can I reduce the size of it ? This is my priority

**dll's are about 15 MB**
(Xamarin forms, maps, other third party libraries. Since I am targeting for 7 and 64. I see libraryX.dll, libraryX.aotdata.arm64, libraryX.aotdata.arm7)
This is right I believe.

**Images are about 20 MB**

I am planning to reduce even further by using 'https://tinypng.com/' to flaten and putting all images assets for 'thinning'. Also probably wants to use on demand resources option but its low priority

Please let me know. Any help / suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Xamarin Forum link : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103470/xamarin-ios-file-size-is-too-big-tried-all-the-possible-options/p1?new=1

Thank you.

Comment: Are you viewing the Debug output or the Release output? Don't benchmark on the Debug output if that is what you are doing.

Comment: I am looking at ipa that was created for release. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using an icon font would help to reduce the size of your IPA as you would be replacing multiple versions of icons with a vector graphic from the font. I have had a lot of success with this approach. [Details here](https://medium.com/@nirinchev/using-icon-fonts-with-xamarin-forms-16da98c98e05) and [also here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31530/fontawesome-label-heres-how)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I followed above approach as I can only add few from fontawesome

Answer (score 1):

There isn't very much that can be done to minimize the size a part from what you've already done. (linking/link away/strip debug code) 
[Here](https://gist.github.com/jgold6/a1e60e0bb24ccdd2b2b8) you can find a list of best practice to apply to reduce your app's size and there is also a Xamarin section dedicated to [Linking on iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/). (limit generics/download resources at runtime/limit structs)

You can dig finding out which assemblies are the most hunger for space.
Check out the `mtouch-cache` folder of the `obj`folder of your build: 
`ls -laS *.o`

In my case:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff  9276292 Sep 13 10:03 mscorlib.dll.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff  5741840 Sep 13 10:03 Newtonsoft.Json.dll.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff  5359900 Sep 13 10:13 ****.Core.dll.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff  4823812 Sep 13 10:03 System.Core.dll.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff  3929056 Sep 13 10:13 ****.iOS.exe.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff  3729004 Sep 13 10:03 NodaTime.dll.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff  3218980 Sep 13 10:03 System.Xml.dll.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff  3014548 Sep 13 10:03 System.dll.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff  2985844 Sep 13 10:03 Xamarin.iOS.dll.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff  2165576 Sep 13 10:03 Ninject.dll.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff  1686992 Sep 13 10:13 registrar.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff  1569908 Sep 13 10:03 System.Net.Http.dll.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff   903048 Sep 13 10:03 SQLite.Net.dll.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff   620200 Sep 13 10:03 ****-iOS.dll.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff   566972 Sep 13 10:03 ********.dll.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff   430432 Sep 13 10:03 ********.dll.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff   396776 Sep 13 10:03 SDWebImage.dll.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff   318632 Sep 13 10:03 ********.dll.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff   268884 Sep 13 10:03 SwipeTableCellBinding.dll.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff   235960 Sep 13 10:03 Flurl.dll.o
-rw-r--r--  1 hichame.yessou  staff   232304 Sep 13 10:03 MonoTouch.******.dll.o
```

Secondly, if you try to build an **empty** Xamarin.iOS project it will result in an 37 MB .ipa, so I do think that it's a resonable size 77 MB for a full project. 
Plus, the App Store restriction for WiFi-only apps are set to 100 MB.

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply. When I created base app with same PCL approach Project.iOS took like 28 MB. Full project is 42MB. Probably not much anything I can do there.  I did able to reduce size for images by flattening. It saved 65% size. Now the ipa is about 60MB.