# How to reduce ipa size Xamarin.ios

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ipa

I am trying to reduce my ipa size, but cant succeed. I tried with linking SDK assemblies only but when the app is archived it shows 189 MB of the app store and 75mb for ipa. I tried different options but it never worked.

Then I looked into my bin folder and I found out that Xamarin.swift4 is taking about 80 MB of the size, When I removed that package my ipda was reduced to 34mb and playstore size was reduced to 89 MB, but because of this my app crashed instantly after opening. So it means that I can not remove Xamarin.swift 4 libraries.

I have attached my bin folder pic and packages.congifg file, let me know if there is any solution

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Answers" version="1.4" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Crashlytics" version="1.4" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="dannycabrera.GetiOSModel" version="1.4.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Fabric" version="1.4" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="iOSCharts" version="3.1.1.2" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.4.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.AppContext" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Console" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Globalization.Calendars" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.3" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Net.Sockets" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Handles" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XmlDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="UITextFieldShaker" version="2017.10.19" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugin.Connectivity" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="3.0.0.446417" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="ZXing.Net.Mobile" version="2.3.2" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Swift4" version="4.0.0.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Swift4.Core" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Swift4.CoreAudio" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Swift4.CoreData" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Swift4.CoreFoundation" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Swift4.CoreGraphics" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Swift4.CoreImage" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Swift4.CoreMedia" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Swift4.Darwin" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Swift4.Dispatch" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Swift4.Foundation" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Swift4.Metal" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Swift4.ObjectiveC" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Swift4.OS" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Swift4.QuartzCore" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Swift4.UIKit" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin iOS ipa file size issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286265/xamarin-ios-ipa-file-size-issue)

Comment: You are using `Charts 3.0+` and that 3rd-party iOS framework requires Swift libraries. Why that requires an .Net assembly in the final iPA is very strange as I use Charts 3 also but have my own bindings, the swift frameworks (libswiftXXXX) are required to be bundled but no additional assemblies. Are you sure that these are used in the final iPA packaging? If so I would post an issue on Flash3001's repo and ask...

Comment: @SushiHangover I tried removing ioshcarts and xamarin.swift libraries but still the ipa size was only reduced to 71mb from 76mb and playstore size was reduced to 172.89mb from 189mb

Answer (score 0):

You should remove **only** the libraries you don't use in your project.
Two weeks ago my ipa file was at almost 200 MB, then I deleted all the Swift libraries that was unnecessary for the project, and now I create smaller ipa files than the previous one (80 MB).
So you need to check your application, see if you have unnecessary libraries and delete it, this way you will reduce the ipa size.

Comment: Which of the libraries would you recommend removing, sinze I have removed swift4 libraries which only reduced to 71 mb from 76 mb.

Comment: As I said, the libraries you don't use in your project, you need to analyze your app and decide what can be removed. If all the libraries that your project have are important and are being used, your ipa file will have this size and you can't remove any of the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into the 'Linker', which you will find in your iOS build options within Visual Studio

A brief overview:

1. Don't Link - all assemblies left untouched (largest ipa size)
2. Link SDK assemblies only - reduces size of SDK (Xamarin.iOS) assemblies by removing everything that your application doesn't use
3. Link all assemblies - reduces size of all assemblies by removing everything that your application doesn't use (smallest ipasize)

Note that 'link all assemblies' can cause issues as the linker can't always determine what is used and can therefore remove code from an assembly that is actually required (think web services, reflection, serialisation). In such cases you can set a manual mtouch argument to prevent a specific assembly (or assemblies) from having being touched by the linker as below:

```
--linkskip=NameOfAssemblyToSkipWithoutFileExtension
```

or

```
--linkskip=NameOfFirstAssembly --linkskip=NameOfSecondAssembly
```

A real use case I've come across where the above is necessary is when using Entity Framework with Xamarin.iOS, as the linker removes code which is then called using reflection which causes the app to crash.

The full documentation for the Linker is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=vsmac